# input and select tag cannot be clicked

Tags: html, css

I don't know if there is some problem but I can't click on an input and a select tag, i tried everything on the code, I made changes and nothing, nothing solves it, the whole code is below

```css
.mt-35 {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

` .mb-35 {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.fs-90 {
  font-size: 90%;
}

.pd-15 {
  padding: 15;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 mt-35 pd-15">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Registro de Publicaciones</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
              <label class="col-md-4 fs-90">ID Converis</label>
              <label class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 fs-90">Año de publicación</label>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-35">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID Converis">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-35">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Año de publicación">
              </div>
              <label class="col-md-4 fs-90">DOI</label>
              <label class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 fs-90">Autores</label>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-35">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DOI">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control" multiple size="3" style="margin-bottom: 35px;">
                  <option value="1">AUTOR</option>
                  <option value="2">AUTOR</option>
                  <option value="3">AUTOR</option>
                  <option value="4">AUTOR</option>
                  <option value="5">AUTOR</option>
                  <option value="6">AUTOR</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <label class="col-md-4 fs-90">Tipo de publicación</label>
              <label class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">Hola</label>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-35">
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">Artículo</option>
                  <option value="2">Revisión</option>
                  <option value="3">Material editorial</option>
                  <option value="4">Reporte de caso</option>
                  <option value="5">Carta</option>
                  <option value="6">Libro</option>
                  <option value="7">Capítulo de Libro</option>
                  <option value="8">Resumen</option>
                  <option value="9">Presentación</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-35">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="visibility: hidden;">
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox col-md-offset-3">
                <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Colaboración Nacional</label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox col-md-offset-3">
                <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Colaboración Internacional</label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox col-md-offset-3">
                <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Colaboración UC</label>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="SaveCategory">
                            <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Grabar
                        </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i> Cerrar
                        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need this for today and I dont know what the problem is

Comment: Please, explain what you mean with *"I can't click on an input and a select tag"* Which one? What happens? What you need? Your question is not very clear

Comment: @CalvinNunes I am sorry, look if you see this link http://maquetas-erp.bio.puc.cl/publicacion.asp , try to click the "Año de categoria" input and "Autores" select, you can't, for some reason, only if you tab from the beginning

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to leave SO to click in others sites. Please try to reproduce your issue here, with a [mcve], as said in [ask]

Comment: But by what you said, I think that there's some HTML element above the inputs, have you checked it with devTools?

Comment: I guess you have css that is interfering with the html

Comment: @CalvinNunes I don't have nothing else than that, except for the container

Comment: @RamRaider how?

Comment: looking at the live html by deleting some of the stylesheets I am able to click in the various fields and dropdowns that were unavailable before... check your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your div named ' `checkbox col-md-offset-3` ' is on the top of your select box " Año de categoria "

try remove `position : relative` from the nested checkbox class or try to add " `position: relative; z-index:10;` " on the nested `col-md-6 mb-35`

```css
.mt-35 {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.mb-35 {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.fs-90 {
  font-size: 90%;
}

.pd-15 {
  padding: 15;
}

.clickfix .col-md-6{position: relative:z-index:10}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 mt-35 pd-15">
        <div class="panel panel-primary clickfix">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Registro de Publicaciones</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
              <label class="col-md-4 fs-90">ID Converis</label>
              <label class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 fs-90">Año de publicación</label>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-35">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID Converis">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-35">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Año de publicación">
              </div>
              <label class="col-md-4 fs-90">DOI</label>
              <label class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4 fs-90">Autores</label>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-35">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DOI">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control" multiple size="3" style="margin-bottom: 35px;">
                  <option value="1">AUTOR</option>
                  <option value="2">AUTOR</option>
                  <option value="3">AUTOR</option>
                  <option value="4">AUTOR</option>
                  <option value="5">AUTOR</option>
                  <option value="6">AUTOR</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <label class="col-md-4 fs-90">Tipo de publicación</label>
              <label class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">Hola</label>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-35">
                <select class="form-control">
                  <option value="1">Artículo</option>
                  <option value="2">Revisión</option>
                  <option value="3">Material editorial</option>
                  <option value="4">Reporte de caso</option>
                  <option value="5">Carta</option>
                  <option value="6">Libro</option>
                  <option value="7">Capítulo de Libro</option>
                  <option value="8">Resumen</option>
                  <option value="9">Presentación</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 mb-35">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="visibility: hidden;">
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox col-md-offset-3">
                <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Colaboración Nacional</label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox col-md-offset-3">
                <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Colaboración Internacional</label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox col-md-offset-3">
                <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Colaboración UC</label>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="SaveCategory">
                            <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Grabar
                        </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                            <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i> Cerrar
                        </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, THANKS! but I don't know how, can u explain please, i mean, i didnt understand how the checkbox is on top of año categoria

Comment: happy to help you, Mate. Maybe somehow it gets on the top of your select boxes. for that reason you won't be able to click on it. you could add the checkbox in a div, then style it. currently your HTML structure is not good at all.